# Websphere lookup thread pool in java application

Tags: websphere, threadpool

I'm kind of new to WAS so question may be naive. I searched for a while, but was not able to find a solution.

Basically: define a thread pool in WAS console, name it "ac.work.threadpool"

But in the java code, after getting the context, how to lookup it.

Like this?:

```
ctx.lookup("java:ac.work.threadpool")
```

But not working

Answer (score 3):

You can't lookup threadpools in WebSphere Application Server traditional, note that the Admin Console page for threadpools states "Use this page to specify a thread pool for the **server** to use", not for your application.  You can use a WorkManager to manage concurrent work in your application and you can look up the WorkManager via the JNDI name configured when it was created, see IBM KnowledgeCenter topic [Configuring Work Managers](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/asyncbns/tasks/tasb_workmanager.html).  If you're interested in using managed thread factories from the Java EE 7 spec for concurrency (JSR-236), consider looking at the [WebSphere Application Server traditional open beta](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/covr_javaee7.html).